# TMS FlexCel - Open a xlsx generated by EPPlus

Tags: epplus, flexcel

I have created a simple workbook with EPPlus in C# .NET Core (The file is XLSX).

I need to export this workbook to PDF.

I am trying to export using TMS FlexCel for .NET.

But, when the code try to export I get the error below:

FlexCel.Core.FlexCelCoreException: 'Invalid Cell: "#REF!"'

If I save the same workbook as XLS, the code works perfectlly.

Below is my code:

```
            string file = @"D:\Test.xlsx";
            string pdfFile = Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".pdf");

            Excel.SaveAs(new FileInfo(file));

            XlsFile xls = new XlsFile(false);
            xls.Open(file);
            FlexCelPdfExport pdf = new FlexCelPdfExport(xls, true);
            pdf.Export(pdfFile);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The file generated by EPPlus is OpenXml format and the FlexCel doesn't recognize the format.